# Does JAGS have a log function for bases other than e?

Tags: jags, rjags

I am trying to calculate a log with base 2 in JAGS, but can't find a way to implement this.
In the documentation I can't find a way to do this, and I am hoping I am missing something,
or that someone knows a workaround.

Thanks in advance for any help,
Benny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log base 2 (or the binary logarithm) can be calculated with this trick here ([link to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm#Conversion_from_other_bases)). As an example in `R` using the natural log:

```
log_2_result <- log(15, base = 2)

log_2_trick <- log(15) / log(2)

identical(log_2_result, log_2_trick)
[1] TRUE
```

`JAGS` has the `log` function, so you could use a similar approach to above (for `log_2_trick`). An important thing to note, however, is that because `log` is a link function in `JAGS` you can only input a scalar into it.